# Monotouch: How do I display the contents of a file?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextview

I have a file that I create which I want to display to the user.  A UITextView allows the user to edit the file, which I don't want.  Basically it is a report of the data the user has entered, before I have performed calculations (kind of like the preview of an email sent from the iPhone).

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a UITextView and set its Editable property to false.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to display richer content than just text, you could render it to a pdf for display using CoreGraphics or use a UIWebView.